# same component with different styles if user is signed in

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Lets say we have component called Main, iam trying to set up condtion inside of it if user is signed it would have diffent styles, i know it seems easy but iam stuck on it for quit some time.
thanks for any ideas
i had code like this: [image: code snippet]

Comment: Relevant code (and error messages where applicable) need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Having said that... What have you tried and what isn't working?  Within your component, how do you determine if a user is logged in?  What happens when you use that information to conditionally use one class/style vs. another?

Comment: Conditionnaly add a class "logged_used" on the parent element. Use that class in your stylesheets

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your help, Iam still trying to lear how to do this things, I will make new question with hopefully everyhing as it should be. sorry for my misstake

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is change the styles and not the content of the component, rather than having an if statement that renders the same element tree twice (just with different classes), you could use conditionals on the className itself.

```
  className={`className1 ${sign ? 'className2' : `className3`}`}

  //Or if you want to remove classes based on sign
  className={`className1 ${sign ? 'className2' : ''}`}
```

Better yet, install the classnames package from npm and you can do something like this:

```
const aClassname = classNames({ class1: true, class2: sign, class3: !sign });

return <div className={aClassname}></div>
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

Answer (score 0):

The most simplistic solution is to use an  ternary operator like below;

```js
export function App(props) {
  const sign = true;
  return (
    <div className="container">
      { sign ? (
        <div>
          <h1>Logged in!</h1>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h1>Guest</h1>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, this won't be easy to read when your component / different styles scale in size. What you could do is separate the different styles to their own separate components and use conditional rendering to show them.

```js
export function AuthenticatedMain(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Logged in!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export function GuestMain(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Guest</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export function App(props) {
  const sign = true;

  if (sign) {
    return <AuthenticatedMain/>
  }
  return <GuestMain/>
}
```

---